# MySQL | Deleting row from in date range in the middle

Tags: mysql, pdo

I am trying to delete rows dependant upon the date column, I want to be able to delete the row that's in between the specified dates so I always have the oldest row and the newest from kept and the middle row deleted.

I am currently using this code...

```
DELETE t FROM tracking t INNER JOIN users u ON u.id = t.uid WHERE u.name = :name
```

This will delete a single row, which is the earliest row. Somehow I need to delete the row in the middle of 2 rows and the dates being in separate rows too.

[image]

The image shows how the current table is laid out. The highlighted rows are the rows which I would like to delete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one method:

```
DELETE t
    FROM tracking t INNER JOIN
         users u
         ON u.id = t.uid INNER JOIN
         (SELECT t.uid, MIN(tracked_date) as mintd, MAX(tracked_date) as maxtd
          FROM tracking t
          GROUP BY t.uid
         ) tt
         ON t.uid = tt.uid
    WHERE u.name = :name AND
          t.tracked_date NOT IN (tt.mintd, tt.maxtd);
```

The following version probably has better performance:

```
DELETE t
    FROM tracking t INNER JOIN
         users u
         ON u.id = t.uid INNER JOIN
         (SELECT t.uid, MIN(tracked_date) as mintd, MAX(tracked_date) as maxtd
          FROM tracking t INNER JOIN
               users u
               ON u.id = t.uid
          WHERE u.name = :name
          GROUP BY t.uid
         ) tt
         ON t.uid = tt.uid
    WHERE u.name = :name AND
          t.tracked_date NOT IN (tt.mintd, tt.maxtd);
```

It looks more complicated, because of the additional join in the subquery.  But that allows the subquery to filter before aggregating.

Comment: This works but I still end up with 3 rows instead of just the two?

Comment: That was my fault, I had the insert after the delete statement! This worked a charm, thank you!]